# How to calculate percentages in Python

Tags: python, percentage, division

I am making a program in Python to determine the percentage of my marks in various subjects. It is supposed to ask me for my marks and find the percentage but something is wrong. I am rather young, so please don't laugh at my attempt:

```
import os
import time
print ("This is a program to calculate your percentage in your ACADEMICS ")
time.sleep(2)

english = input("Enter your english marks \n \t")
time.sleep(1)

maths = input ("Enter your maths marks \n \t")
time.sleep(1)

science= input ("Enter your science marks \n \t")
time.sleep(1)

print ("OK, i am reviewing your marks, ")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Hmm, verry poor marks, but here is your %")

percentage = english + maths + science /3
print(percentage)
```

but in the end it says that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/COOL BOY/Desktop/percentage.py", line 18, in <module>
    percentage = english + maths + science %3
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your error doesn't match your code and you aren't converting your inputs to integers.

Comment: 1. The error message shows `%` but your code shows `/`. So this error doesn't match the actual code. 2. Meet your new friend [BODMAS](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html)!

Comment: percentage = (english + maths + science )/3

Answer (score 4):

The `input` function returns a string.
When computing `english + maths + science /3` you are adding strings  !
You should convert your inputs to numbers via the `int(string)` or `float(string)` functions.
You can also check whether your strings is made of digit with `'mystring'.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert string to int when asking for inputs, when calculating you are using strings instead of ints.

```
import os
import time
print ("This is a program to calculate your percentage in your ACADEMICS ")
time.sleep(2)


english = int(input("Enter your english marks \n \t"))
time.sleep(1)

maths = int(input("Enter your maths marks \n \t"))
time.sleep(1)


science= int(input("Enter your science marks \n \t"))
time.sleep(1)


print ("OK, i am reviewing your marks, ")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Hmm, verry poor marks, but here is your %")

percentage = (english + maths + science) /3
print(percentage)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Input should be casted by int Ex: `int(input("number"))`
2. Considering MaxScore for a subject is 100 the formula would be

   `percentage=(aquaired marks of all 3 subjects)x100/(3*100)`
3. Percentage should be rounded up by last 2 digits.

The final program would be.

```
import os
import time

maxscore = 100
totalsubjects=3

print ("This is a program to calculate your percentage in your ACADEMICS ")
time.sleep(2)


english = int(input("Enter your english marks \n \t"))
time.sleep(1)

maths = int(input("Enter your maths marks \n \t"))
time.sleep(1)


science= int(input("Enter your science marks \n \t"))
time.sleep(1)


print ("OK, i am reviewing your marks, ")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Hmm, verry poor marks, but here is your %")

percentage = (english + maths + science)*100/(maxscore*totalsubjects)
print(round(percentage,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

the pythonic way

```
import os, time

def get_subject_score(sub):
    time.sleep(2)
    return int(input(f"Enter your {sub} marks : "))  # int or float as you wish

print("This is a program to calculate your percentage in your ACADEMICS")

english = get_subject_score("english")
maths = get_subject_score("math")
science = get_subject_score("science")

print(f"OK, i am reviewing your marks, {(english + maths + science) / 3}")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When ur taking integrer as input it should be `int(input())` instead of `input()` as later takes input as string
2. To Calculate Percentage its should be **Percentage = (Sum Of Aquired Marks)*Max Marks/(3*Max Marks)**

Assuming 100 As Marks **Percentage = (english + maths + science)*100/(3*100)**